# Azure Application Gateway - Allow-listing outside IPs

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have Azure Application Gateway (WAF V2) in which I have configured below 2 sites through Listeners and Rules.

1. public.xyz.com
2. restricted.xyz.com

First domain should be accessible to public and there is no restriction. But the 2nd one should be accessible only to specific Client IP Addresses.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The URL you want to allow public access to shouldn't require any changes. Restricting access to the other can be done by adding a WAF policy and setting up two custom rules.

1. Follow the [guidance on the Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/create-waf-policy-ag#create-a-policy) to create and associate a WAF policy with your WAF.
2. In the custom rules section of the WAF Policy, add a rule to allow access to the IP addresses for that host header value. The priority you set must be higher than the next rule. Not pictured in the image below are the IP addresses and the "Allow traffic" setting.
   [image]
3. Add another rule in the custom rules section to deny traffic to that host header value. Make sure the priority on this is lower than the previous rule. The whitelisted IPs will be granted access on the previous rule and all other requests will fall through and be blocked by this rule. Once you add both rules, make sure to hit Save on the Custom Rules section to apply them, I always forget to do that.
   [image]